# Create Maya Content Browser ui

Tags: user-interface, browser, maya

I've been looking in to creating a ui that is similar to Maya's content browser. I basically want a library that of files that I can preview a play blast and import a file. I looked at maya's mel for the content browser and from what I can tell there's a command that builds the preview and than attaches (parents) it to a formlayout ui. I've been look for any documentation of this but I don't even know the what to search for. Can you guys help?

[image]

Comment: Do you want a library, that provides a ready to use content browser? Or do you want to program it by yourself (what programming language?) Please give us more details on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I want like a pose manger or content browser. I want a ui to pop up in maya with a file directory that can be previewed (playblast) multiple files like the content browser. Mel or python it doesn't matter. I really don't know what to search for or what that ui would be called.

Comment: Since this is a quite complex UI, I recommend to use PySide to build it. This way you can build it from scratch in the exact way you need it. I suppose building a new UI is faster than searching and understanding the whole mel procedures which build the builtin browser in Maya.

Comment: Is there something specifically from that image you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a GUI like this you would have to write it in PYQT/PySide as it have more advanced widgets for UI building.

Here are a list of some of the widgets that are being used.

- QcomboBox
- QtreeWidget
- QlistWidget